# Drawing arbitary pictures on a webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, image, image-generation

I need to display a runtime-generated image (mostly consisting of nice-looking boxes, lines and text) on a webpage. We're currently using ASP.NET MVC3.

The problem is, I haven't really done web development before, and I have no idea how to go about drawing an arbitary diagram on a webpage. Do I use some sort of javascript? How, and what do I use? Do I generate the image on the server somehow and simply display it? Something else?

I have no idea where to even start, let alone solve the actual problem...

Comment: I'd assume you would probably be best using a javascript that grabbed an arbitrary/random picture from a site directory; and placed it in the document zone which you would have to predefine.

Comment: You'll have to explain that a bit more, I haven't really worked with javascript before

Comment: take a look @Roy Dictus. Basically, those articles should tell you how to do what I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the target browser.

If you target the most modern browsers, you can use an HTML5 Canvas and draw on it using JavaScript (see http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/).

If you're targeting other browsers (as well), the easiest is probably to generate an image on the server side (GIF/JPG/PNG). Your HTML page then contains an IMG tag with the SRC parameter set to the page that generates and returns the image. You can find an example at this page: http://www.sitepoint.com/generating-asp-net-images-fly/ (this uses ASP.NET to generate the image).

Comment: What if I later wanted to add some interactivity (clicking on the boxes does something to the image)?

Comment: Then it's a whole different story. Then I'd look at HTML5 interactivity or Silverlight or Flash.

Comment: @thecoop , you would just have to set an onClick(onClick="theFunction()") attribute on the <img> tag or whatever tag you are using to drop the image into. Then, you would program what happens in that function.

Comment: @Bry6n That would depend on the level of interactivity required. An OnClick() would do for very simple interaction, yes...

Comment: Well, that is what he suggested, isn't it? "clicking on the boxes does something". HTML5's interactivity, like you suggested, would be a great approach. I've never used Silverlight but it's users say it's decent. Flash is.. meh. I still hold true to jScript being the best approach to merely interacting with one image.

Answer (score 1):

Roy Dictus fairly well described the overall approach you'll want to take. If you decide to target modern browsers and use javascript, I'd suggest you look at [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/). It's a javascript port of a popular Java library, and the web page has some code samples to show how you can create both static drawings and animations with some simple code.